# How do I change my resolution and aspect ratio for tik tok dimensions?

Tags: export, edit-mode, video

I edit a short video that is 1920x1080 by default I want to change it to tiktok dimensions (1080x1920 9:16) but when I do it distorts the video. How do I make it so it fills instead of stretches. Thank you

Comment: How are you changing your dimensions currently? What process are you using to do this? It may help if you provide screenshots or, if necessary, the .blend file.

Comment: it cannot "fill" you can only size and then crop/cut it.

Answer (score 1):

select your movie, Shift - A -> effect strip -> transfrom

adapt scale values as you need it (change both to same value so i doesn't get distorted), move x and y as you need it

[image]